# NASM does not work on macbook pro

Tags: nasm

NASM does not work on macbook pro pls help me. ./configure is showing errors lke this.

```
Last login: Mon Sep 16 23:35:49 on ttys001 
Penpa-Gyaltsens-MacBook-Pro:~ pen_gyalink$ cd /Users/pen_gyalink/Downloads/nasm-2.10.09-20130723  
Penpa-Gyaltsens-MacBook-Pro:nasm-2.10.09-20130723 pen_gyalink$ ./configure 
-bash: ./configure: No such file or directory 
Penpa-Gyaltsens-MacBook-Pro:nasm-2.10.09-20130723 pen_gyalink$
```

Comment: That "error" is the system telling you it can't find `./configure`. Check your installation again

Comment: And if you install the developer tools, `nasm` will be among them.

Comment: can you tell me more about developer tools? which developer? Xcode developer or something else.

Answer (score 1):

Daily snapshots should contain the `configure` script because they're intended to be used by end users.

The raw git repository does not contain the `configure` script, because it's intended for developers. In order to create the `configure` script in that case you need to run the `autogen.sh` script in the current directory, which will generate the `configure` script.

In general, if you're an end-user, you should download the latest stable copy unless you're looking for newer features/bugfixes for the version you now have.